# How do I calculate the extreme possible values of a population given mean and standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

If I know that the mean value of some random variable in a population is 11.52 and the standard deviation is 18.55182, can I estimate the value of some of the most extreme data points?

My question is inspired by the following article: https://www.rcmalternatives.com/2012/03/if-bill-gates-were-as-tall-as-his-money/

> If Bill Gates were as tall as his money, he would be a "300 mile tall
>   man."

Comment: Yes, you can, if you know or assume the values are normally distributed (as in the link to your quote). Check the wikipedia page for normal distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: Assuming a normal population estimated to have $\mu \approx 11.52$ and $\sigma \approx 18.55,$ then (in the spirit of the Empirical Rule) it would be rare to see observations above $11.52 + 3(18.55) \approx 67.2.$ The actual distribution of the maximum of a normal sample depends on the sample size $n.$ For $n = 50,$ the average of the max observation from this normal population is about 53 (from simulation).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not assume a particular distribution then you can not say very much about extreme values beyond something like:

- either at least one value in the population is  $\mu+\sigma$ or more, or at least one value is $\mu-\sigma$ or below: in your example, you cannot have all the values strictly between $-7.03182$ and $30.07182$
- if all the values are non-negative, then the largest value must be at least $\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu}$: in your example the largest value would then have to be more than $41.39587$